# The app Crashes when i add -notifyDataSetChanged()- the code run perfect and get the posts in the database but

Tags: kotlin, adapter

this code is inside a fragment I have a recycler view and the array list all set
the code runs perfect and get the posts in the database and get the Log messages i have entered   until I add this line

postAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

which is line 81 on my code I have Bolded it so you know what I talk about

am new to coding so any small help will help me

```
    package com.example.foonection.Fragments

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.foonection.AddNewPostActivity
import com.example.foonection.Post
import com.example.foonection.PostAdapter

import com.example.foonection.R
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_feed_seller.view.*
import java.util.ArrayList

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 */
class FeedSellerFragment : Fragment() {

    private var postAdapter: PostAdapter? = null
    private var postList: MutableList<Post>? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed_seller, container, false)

        var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.timeline_view_feed)
        val linearLayoutManger = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        linearLayoutManger.reverseLayout = true
        linearLayoutManger.stackFromEnd = true
        recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManger

        postList = ArrayList()
        postAdapter = context?.let { PostAdapter(it,postList as ArrayList<Post>) }
        recyclerView.adapter = postAdapter

        retrievePosts()

        view.add_post_feed_btn.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("Log","Add Post btn Clicked")
            val intent = Intent(context, AddNewPostActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }



        return view
    }

    private fun retrievePosts(){

        Log.d("Log","Trying To Retrieve Posts")

        val postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts")
        postsRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                postList?.clear()

                if (p0.exists())
                {
                    Log.d("Log","p0 is existed")
                    for (snapshot in p0.children)
                    {
                        Log.d("Log","for loop snapshot")
                        val post = snapshot.getValue(Post :: class.java)
                        postList!!.add(post!!)
                        **postAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()**

                    }

                }


            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

call notifyDataSetChanged like this

```
 postAdapter?.let{
 it.notifyDataSetChanged()
 }
```

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't work i put a Log msg before the it.notifyDataSetChanged() it shows the log message but crashes also and don't show any change on the recycle view before the crash

Comment: can you post your logcats

Comment: I have put the code like this 
                        postAdapter?.let {
                            Log.d("Log","entered the it post adapter")
                            it.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }

Comment: the logcasts is like this 
- Background execution not allowed:
-Trying To Retrieve Posts
-p0 is existed
-for loop snapshot
-entered the it post adapter
-for loop snapshot
-entered the it post adapter
-for loop snapshot
-entered the it post adapter

Comment: also chaaged the val post to var post same thing